# When the primitive of a function is the function itself, then $f(x)=0$ (using the FTC)?

Tags: real-analysis

Let f: R → R be a continuous function such that:

$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$

Show that $f(x)=0$; for all $x$.

I did it like this:
According to the statement, $ f (x) $ is already the primitive of $ f (x) $, so $ f (x) $ is equal to $ F (x) $. By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we already know that $ F´ (x) = f (x) $ just like $ f (x) = F (x) $ we have $ F´ (x) = f´ (x) $ and therefore $ f (x) = f´ (x) $. I don't know how to show that it's zero.

Comment: The question is about the definite integral from zero, not about the primitive. The nuance is quite significant.

Comment: How boring. I'd like to see a *dis*continuous function such that $$f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$;-)

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is continuous, all its antiderivatives are differentiable and the differential equation

$$f'(x)=f(x)$$ holds.

We know that the general solution of this ODE is $f(x)=ce^x$ (including $c=0$, from $f'(x)=f(x)=0$).

Now as $f(0)=0$, only the solution with $c=0$ is possible.

Comment: The only difference between your answer and my answer is that I explain How to arrive to the general solution and you do not explain it.
Sorry, but this is very prepotent.

Comment: @TitoEliatron: I don't think so.

Answer (score -2):

If $f(x)=f'(x)$ then $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=1$. Integrating, you get that
$\ln f(x)=x+K$ whence $f(x)=ce^x$ for some $c\in\Bbb R$.

But you also know that $f(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, so $f(0)=\int_0^0f(t)dt=0$.

Putting altogether $0=f(0)=ce^0=c$ and you'll get that $f(x)=0$.

EDIT: Thh above argument works whenever $f\ne0$. Observe that, in fact, $c\ne0$ but $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution of $f'(x)=f(x)$. So we can write that all solutions of $f'(x)=f(x)$ are $f(x)=ce^x$ with $c\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: If $f(x)=0$, then any reasoning on $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ is flawed.

Comment: But $f(x)=0$ is a trivial solution of $f'=f$. I think is better to show the way to solve this ODE better than giving the general solution.

Comment: No, you cannot use $f(x)\ne 0$ to prove $f(x)=0$. Your argument is wrong and showing the OP bad practice.

Comment: By the way, solving $f'(x)=f(x)$ is certainly *not* the same as solving $f(x)=\displaystyle\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: $f(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is the same as $f'(x)=f(x)$ AND ·$f(0)=0$. And that is what is posted in the answer.